# How to call an activity from a class extending Overlay

Tags: android

I have a requirement of getting a full screen image on clicking the tagged points on the map...I short to call an activity from a class extending Overlay,however i am getting the following error

"The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type MapLocationFace"

when i use this piece of code to call the activity from the onTap function :

Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setClass(mapView.getContext(), getnohsib.class); startActivity(intent);

Note : MapLocationFace class is extending Overlay...

whats the solution....thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startActivity` method is to be called on a context object. try calling the startActivity like this `mapView.getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Works perfect...thanks a bunch varun...i had wasted/invested 24 hrs to get this... once again thankyou for helping me out....